# Why is there no dialogue options for Serana to follow me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For some odd reason I can't get Serana to follow me and now there is no option for her to follow me when I open dialogue options. I need her though to finish the vampire quest line. I have tried attacking her, waiting, magic, everything.

Comment: @Zommuter Merging's a good idea. I voted to closed this as a dupe of the older question because that's the usual practice, and also to [discourage duplicates of older questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165946/162827). As a workaround to the "no upvoted or accepted answer" close vote restriction, you could vote to close this question as a duplicate of the older one by upvoting an answer there, closing this one as a duplicate, then (optionally) reverting your upvote.